# How to display alert popup before execute next line in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I want to display alert/message in my web application. I tried the below code but the alert displays after all lines of code execution.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Only alert Message');", true);
```

But i want to display i middle of line of code execution, is it possible if it possible please help me..

Comment: You cannot. `RegisterStartupScript` as you can read will **register** a startup script not call it. Also this script will be called only when response is received by client and processed. You can try a workaround for your scenario. Create a hidden button, and define a function to be processed after alert to this button. Then in your script, show alert and call click of this button.

Comment: @Rajesh hello rajesh thanks for your response. could you explain in detail please..

Comment: As rajesh mentioned, it is not possible because script is run on the client side that means Asp.net has to be render the response and will also register scripts if any provided and give it back to client then only client can run the script.

Comment: @viru  is there any alter native for this..

Comment: Read my description. I have already mentioned a workaround in it.

Comment: @Rajesh ya i created a hidded button, and defined a function in click event of that button, then also alter box shows after all line of code run, can you provide any code sample..?

Answer (score 2):

As I have already commented:

> You cannot. RegisterStartupScript as you can read will register a startup script not call it. Also this script will be called only when response is received by client and processed. You can try a workaround for your scenario. Create a hidden button, and define a function to be processed after alert to this button. Then in your script, show alert and call click of this button.

Your function might look like this:

```
public string myFunction(){
  int a = 123;
  .
  .
  .

  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Only alert Message');", true); 

  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  return str;

}
```

You have to split this function in 2 parts:

```
public string myFunction1(){
  int a = 123;
  .
  .
  .

  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Only alert Message');", true); 

  return str;
}

public string myFunction2(){
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .

}
```

and associate `myFunction1` to original event and `myFunction2` to hidden button. Then update your script to:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Only alert Message'); document.getElementById('<% hiddenBtn.clientId %>').click()", true);
```

This will call remaining code and process logic.

**Note** *This is a **work-around**. Ideally you should try to split functionality and try and use background processing.*